Is there a way to get the "run" button on each code cell for Jupyter Notebook 7.0.8?
I previous version of Jupyter notebook there has been inline 'run' buttons that would be to the left of every code cells. I am on 7.0.8 and I can't figure it out.
Some have suggested to go through the files and change a few things, but I believe that is for Jupyter Labs and not for Jupyter notebook.

In theory this is handled by an extension you can install, see here and here, since Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab components. However, that is very much in theory and may not be perfected yet. Indeed I just tested the way I describe to use pip to install jupyterlab_play_cell_button  with Jupyter Notebook v7.0.4 & v 7.2.0, and while it is clunky in that the small button shows up on top of the typical cell toolbar on the far right, it is there.

I didn't have luck with jlab-enhanced-cell-toolbar with Jupyter Notebook v7.0.4 or v7.2.0.
